# Interactions between Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have two classes (A & B) which implements Runnable.

Both threads are executed in this way:

```
A a = new A();
new Thread(a).start();

B b = new B();
new Thread(b).start();
```

I need to stop/wait/resume thread A inside thread B.

How does it's possible?

Comment: If `A` and `B` inherit from `Thread` why are you passing them _into_ `Thread`? This seems like a gross abuse of inheritance to me, simply inheriting from `Thread` to inherit `extends Runnable`. Further, without very good reason you should never inherit from `Thread`. In short - **always** `implements Runnable` and **never** `extends Thread`.

Comment: Can you give us more information about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can't just stop tread.As markspace commented, it is possible, but you should do it carefully and in some special cases

[Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

> Why is Thread.stopdeprecated?
>
> Because it is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread causes it to unlock all the monitors that it has locked. (The monitors are unlocked as theThreadDeath exception propagates up the stack.)

Comment: Well, you can.  You just usually shouldn't.  There's some situations where it is acceptable to use Thread.stop().  You just need to think very carefully before you do it.

Comment: So you're suggesting me this quote in the 4° paragraph: "Most uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running.". Actually I had turned my solution into this but I thought it was a old-style way so as to guess if there was other ways to do that using some Thread functions. But now it works well. Thank you Sergey!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pause/resume threads in java. If you want this, you should implement it on your own - for example wait on some condition.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/AdamSkywalker/bef2751a850181b03761) you can see an example, how to make thread wait on mutex and later notify it. Anyway, it is possible only if thread performs some periodical stuff. If thread action is solid, there is no way to achieve your goal.

Comment: `Thread.suspend()` and `Thread.resume()` are deprecated, but they are still available.

Comment: @markspace technically we are able to eat nails, but I won't suggest it to anyone :)

Comment: But suspend() and resume() are actually useful in some circumstances.  Deprecated does not mean "never."  Your analogy fails because you exaggerate too much -- calling a deprecated method is nothing like eating nails.

Comment: It can cause a dead lock. Maybe it is not too much, but it is dangerous.